# Change next list element during iteration?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, iterator

Imagine you have a list of points in the 2D-space. I am trying to find symmetric points.

For doing that I iterate over my list of points and apply symmetry operations. So suppose I apply one of these operations to the first point and after this operation it is equal to other point in the list. These 2 points are symmetric.

So what I want is to erase this other point from the list that I am iterating so in this way my iterating variable say "i" won't take this value. Because I already know that it is symmetric with the first point.

I have seen similar Posts but they remove a value in the list that they have already taken. What I want is to remove subsequent values.

Comment: you can have a separate list or set maintaining the found points and check for `if not in` whenever you iterate.

Comment: please post what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is a bad idea to remove values from a list you are iterating over. There are, however, another ways to skip the symmetric points. For example, you can check for each point if you have seen a symmetric one before:

```
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    if symmetric(point) not in points[:i]:
        # Do whatever you want to do
```

Here `symmetric` produces a point according to your symmetry operation. If your symmetry operation connects more that two points you can do

```
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    for sympoint in symmetric(point):
        if sympoint in points[:i]:
            break
    else:
        # Do whatever you want to do
```

Comment: this has a linear complexity.

Comment: @garg10may I think it is even quadratic, but I'm not sure there is a faster way. Worst-case is when there are no symmetric points, so for every point you have to test the whole list. Best case is all points are symmetric, and then my solution is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever symmetric points turn out to be True add them to a set, since set maintains unique elements and look up is `O(1)` you can use if `point not in set` condition.

```
if point not in s:
    #test for symmetry
    if symmetric:
        s.add(point)
```